# Need help with translating operating instructions

Tags: translation

Could anyone spare a minute or two to help me out with this?

I'm here in Taiwan for a few days. Long story short I need to wash my cloths but don't know how to operate this machine. Nobody here speaks a word of English. Could someone please explain to me the general operating instructions? Thanks a bunch!

[image][image]

Comment: Are you sure there’s no English instructions? The top of the machine in the second photo seems like English instrcutions.

Answer (score 3):

I translated a usage step, you can try it out.
[image]
[image]